# sql constraint for checking for two uppercase letters followed by numeric values

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, case-sensitive

i have the following sql check and it accepts values that are supposed to be two uppercase letters followed by 3 numeric values.

---

```
CREATE TABLE Project(
projectID       NCHAR(5)         NOT NULL       PRIMARY KEY,
                                       CHECK(projectID LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
projectName   NVARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL        UNIQUE,
budget      MONEY           NOT NULL)
```

---

**how do you make it so that it will only accept uppercase letters followed by 3 numbers for the projectID?** ex.
it should reject values like 'au123' and accept values like  'AU123'.

Comment: Wait... is the above table check working or not?  It's unclear.  By my read, it looks like it should work.

Comment: It shouldn't work. "LIKE" does not do regexp, just wildcards (?, _). For example, SQL Anywhere 11 seems to introduce a new keyword "REGEXP" to be able to perform a regexp match.

Comment: @Sheepsimulator: If it is SQL Server chances are it will not work, since most SQL Server installations are case insensitive, so that [A-Z] would also match the letter 'a' @Pascal: SQL Server allows non-standard patterns in `like` but nowhere close to full regexp. The pattern given is valid SQL Server syntax.

Comment: the above statement works, but its case insensitive and it will accept strings like 'ab247' instead of forcing it to accept 'AB247'

Comment: @Shannon ok, thanks, I did not know. Changing the behaviour of LIKE seems to me like a bad design idea... People dealing with multi-DBMS queries (e.g. me) will just have to escape LIKE specificaly for SQL Server, in case the (SQL standard) LIKE pattern happens to contain brackets...

Comment: Make the database case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare a case-sensitive collation in your CHECK constraint:

```
Create Table Project    
    (
    ProjectId nchar(5) not null Primary Key
    , ProjectName nvarchar(20) not null Unique
    , Budget money not null
    , Constraint CK_Project 
         Check ( ProjectId Like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]' Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 10g:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE CHECK_CHECK (PROJECT_ID NCHAR(5) NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE CHECK_CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_CHECK_CK01
  2   CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(PROJECT_ID, '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 'c'));

Table altered.

SQL> insert into check_check values ('au123');
insert into check_check values ('au123')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (MED_AUDIT.CHECK_CHECK_CK01) violated

SQL> insert into check_check values ('AU123');

1 row created.
```

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE() seems to be on track to be part of a SQL 2011 ANSI standard, replacing a "SIMILAR TO" which is (is it?) part of a SQL 2008.